# Why does HTML code wrap around

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to design an org chart. The issue I have is that it wraps at the end of the page, instead of being scrollable on the horizontal.

```css
div {
  padding-left: 20px;
  padding-right: 20px;
  text-align: center;
  float: left;
  border: solid 1px #f1f1f1;
  border-top: solid 1px #ccc;
  border-tottom: none;
  color: #ccc;
  margin: 8px;
}

span {
  padding: 10px;
  min-height: 30px;
  background: #3f47f2;
  color: orange;
}

p {
  clear=both;
}
```

```html
<div>
  |<br />
  <span>Cap</span>
  <p>&nbsp;</p>
  <div>
    |<br />
    <span>CT-1</span>
    <p>&nbsp;</p>
    <div>
      |<br />
      <span>CT-1-A</span>
    </div>
    <div>
      |<br />
      <span>CT-1-B</span>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div>
    |<br />
    <span>CT-2</span>
    <p>&nbsp;</p>
    <div>
      |<br />
      <span>CT-2-A</span>
    </div>
    <div>
      |<br />
      <span>CT-2-B</span>
    </div>
    <div>
      |<br />
      <span>CT-2-C</span>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div>
    |<br />
    <span>CT-3</span>
    <p>&nbsp;</p>
    <div>
      |<br />
      <span>CT-3-A</span>
    </div>

  </div>
</div>
```

If you run the snippet it shows what I do NOT want.

What I want is it to be on 3 rows as per this crude example:

```
                                CAP
        CT1                      CT2                     CT3
 CT1-A         CT1-B         CT2-A  CT2-B  CT2-C            CT3-A
```

I don't know how to achieve this. Nor do I know why it doesn't do this. Even if I try to give it a width of 1000% it still wraps!

Comment: you need to use columns

Comment: @TemaniAfif what do you mean, `you need to use columns`

Comment: i put my answer, you need to use classes and not only apply CSS on div and span

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Added `white-space: nowrap; display: inline-block;` to `div`

Removed `float` rule declared and invalid (typo) rule "border-tottom: none;"

```css
div {
  padding-left: 20px;
  padding-right: 20px;
  text-align: center;
  border: solid 1px #f1f1f1;
  border-top: solid 1px #ccc;
  color: #ccc;
  margin: 8px;    
  white-space: nowrap;
  display: inline-block;
}

span {
  padding: 10px;
  min-height: 30px;
  background: #3f47f2;
  color: orange;
}

p {
  clear=both;
}
```

```html
<div>
  |<br />
  <span>Cap</span>
  <p>&nbsp;</p>
  <div>
    |<br />
    <span>CT-1</span>
    <p>&nbsp;</p>
    <div>
      |<br />
      <span>CT-1-A</span>
    </div>
    <div>
      |<br />
      <span>CT-1-B</span>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div>
    |<br />
    <span>CT-2</span>
    <p>&nbsp;</p>
    <div>
      |<br />
      <span>CT-2-A</span>
    </div>
    <div>
      |<br />
      <span>CT-2-B</span>
    </div>
    <div>
      |<br />
      <span>CT-2-C</span>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div>
    |<br />
    <span>CT-3</span>
    <p>&nbsp;</p>
    <div>
      |<br />
      <span>CT-3-A</span>
    </div>

  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to add `min-width` to container div.

So here it is `min-width:1024px;overflow:auto;`

https://jsfiddle.net/t4vmy2vj/1/

Comment: This is great, but what if the min-width is not known? The above works for the example I've given where the first row (cap) only has 3 children, but the first row (cap) could have 30 children!